# Sequelize create transaction with include and junction table

Tags: node.js, many-to-many, sequelize.js

I am trying to insert a new record that is associated to 2 other entities via junction tables. Like this:

Staff -< deploymentCrew >- Deployment -< deploymentEquipment >- Equipment

Staff And deployment tables:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {

  var Staff = sequelize.define('staff', {

    _id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },

    _firstname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      notEmpty: true
    },

    _lastname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },

    _phonework: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },

    _phonehome: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },

    _img: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },

    _emailpersonal: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },

    _emailwork: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },

    _position: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },

    _notes: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },

    _status: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      defaultValue: 'active'
    }

  });

  return Staff;

};


module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {

  var Deployment = sequelize.define('deployment', {

    _id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },

    _datedeployed: {
      type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
      notEmpty: true
    },

    _datereturned: {
      type: Sequelize.DATEONLY
    },

    _city: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },

    _province: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },

    _country: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },


    _unitnumber: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },

    _comments: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT
    },

    _productid: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },

    _contractid: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },

    _deploymenttypeid: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },

    _finalsold: {
      type: Sequelize.NUMERIC(17,3)
    },

    _pricing: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
      get: function () {
        return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue('value'));
      },
      set: function (value) {
        this.setDataValue('value', JSON.stringify(value));
      }
    },

    _status: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      defaultValue: 'active'
    },

    createdBy: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }

  });


  return Deployment;

};
```

My code for the junction tables is just like this:

```
  module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {

  var DeploymentEquipment = sequelize.define('deploymentEquipment', {

  });

  DeploymentEquipment.associate = function(models){
    models.equipment.belongsToMany(models.deployment, {through: models.deploymentEquipment, foreignKey: 'equipmentId'});
    models.deployment.belongsToMany(models.equipment, {through: models.deploymentEquipment, foreignKey: 'deploymentId'});
  };


  return DeploymentEquipment;

};


module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {

  var DeploymentCrew = sequelize.define('deploymentCrew', {

    _timex: {
      type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
      notEmpty: true
    },

    _dateon: {
      type: Sequelize.DATEONLY
    },

    _dateoff: {
      type: Sequelize.DATEONLY
    },

    _role: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }

  });

  DeploymentCrew.associate = function(models){
    models.staff.belongsToMany(models.deployment, {through: models.deploymentCrew, foreignKey: 'staffId'});
    models.deployment.belongsToMany(models.staff, {through: models.deploymentCrew, foreignKey: 'deploymentId'});
  };


  return DeploymentCrew;

};
```

That all seems to work great. But my create statement leaves out the deploymentid in the insert statement. Here is my code:

```
  var deployment = req.body;
  var crew = req.body._deploymentcrew;
  var equipment = req.body._deploymentequipment;

    //insert new deployment - start transaction, add deployment, get ID, loop through crew, loop through equipment
    models.sequelize.transaction(t =>{
      var promises = [];
      return models.deployment.create(req.body, {transaction: t}).then(function(newDeployment) {
        for(var i=0; i < equipment.length; i++){
          var equip = equipment[i];
          equip.deploymentid = newDeployment.id;
          equip.equipmentId = equipment[i].id;
          var newPromise = models.deploymentEquipment.create(equip, promises.push(newPromise));
        }

        for(var i=0; i < crew.length; i++){
          var staff = crew[i];
          staff.deploymentid = newDeployment.id;
          staff.staffId = crew[i].staff.id;
          var newPromise = models.deploymentCrew.create(staff, promises.push(newPromise));
        }

        return Promise.all(promises)
      });
```

When I look at the console, this is the insert statement:

Executing (default): INSERT INTO `deploymentCrews` (`_timex`,`_dateon`,`_dateoff`
,`_role`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`staffId`) VALUES ('2018-03-01','2018-03-12',N
ULL,'lead','2018-03-02 19:21:10','2018-03-02 19:21:10',5);

Notice that there is staffId, but no deploymentId. Any thoughts why? 
I have tried using include:[models._deploymentcrew] but am unsure of that way to do things with transactions.

Any advice would be very appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you add Staff and Deployment table definitions? @enfrost

Comment: I have updated the answer. Let me know this works@enfrost

Comment: Huh I tried that and same issue. I also tried return models.deployment.create(deployment, {include: [models.deploymentCrew, models.deploymentEquipment]}); and got the error deploymentCrew is not associated to deployment!  I also made sure to delete all foreign keys from the database, drop the tables and resync. So strange, I'll keep playing around

Comment: Yeah keep trying ☺️ Post the answer, when u solved it. Interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating N:M associations, we need to **specify foreignkeys of both the tables** as follows

```
Staff.associate = function(models){
    Staff.belongsToMany(models.deployment, {through: models.deploymentCrew, foreignKey: 'staffId'});
};

Deployment.associate = function(models) {
   Deployment.belongsToMany(models.staff, {through: models.deploymentCrew, foreignKey: 'deploymentId'});
};
```

Add the above to the respective table definitions and remove association in deploymentCrew

Comment: I didn't specify those, but when I look at the tables subsequently created from my original statement, the foreign keys are already defined. Is that normal behavior?

Comment: Yes. Because those are primary keys. If this answer cleared your doubt. Do mark the answer  as verified so it might be helpful for others. @enfrost

Comment: I specified both foreign keys as per your example for both junction tables. Dropped the tables, synced and the query sequelize generates still leaves out deploymentId

Comment: It should work, make sure you don't have any typos error by mistake@enfrost

Comment: Hmm, I've triple checked an no typos. Maybe I have to utilize the include  parameter?

Comment: Can you add both tables definitions to the question?

Comment: I've added the tables

Comment: When I tried your solution, I put the associations in the main tables like you said but did not remove the associations from the junction tables. Somehow that was causing the problem. All good now!